# Get json data and convert to array using Laravel

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel, typeahead.js

I am trying to use typeahead. How to fetch json data and convert to jquery array like states? I have read the documentation but no luck with this.
(I use, 1.9.1 jquery, Laravel 5.1)

The below is working but the states array is static. I want to fetch data from MySql database async. How to do this?

jquery:

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

My route is:

```
Route::get('search', array('as' => 'searchlive', 'uses' => 'HistoryController@searchlive'));
```

My controller:

```
public function searchlive(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request->thesearch;
        $games = Game::where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orwhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orwhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->take(5)->get();

        return Response()->json($games);
    }
```

Comment: if you `dd($games)`, what do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to fetch json data if you simply needs array into your typeahead jquery code. Simply makes an array into controller and pass it to your typeahead code, Like:

```
public function searchlive(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->thesearch;
    $games = Game::where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orwhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orwhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->take(5)->get();

       $gamesarray = $games->toArray();
       return view('yourbladefilename', compact(['gamesarray']))
}
```

And in your blade file replace:

```
    var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];
```

to

```
var states = {!! $gamesarray !!}
```

Hope it Helps..If any issue Pls comment..

Comment: Firstly, searchlive function, is my second class and gamesarray variable didn't recognized as value. 
Secondly request of sql is need to be asynchronous to fetch only the requested data not everything from the beginning. Good try though.
My first class that returns the view is:

public function index(Request $request)
    {   
        $games = Game::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
                
        return view('webapp.scores', compact('games'));
    }

Comment: You can customize above code according to your requirements too.

Comment: I need an ajax function to return these values into javascript array. The above code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

showing like this on laravel livewire
[search function](https://prnt.sc/GaQ30o-sSfqb)

[Js script](https://prnt.sc/8SzKmjrHe8SB)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Java script code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
    return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var matches, substringRegex;
        // an array that will be populated with substring matches
        matches = [];
        // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
        substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
        // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
        // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
        $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
        if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
            matches.push(str);
        }
        });
        cb(matches);
    };
    };
    var states = new Array();
    <?php 
    if(isset($getDecisionTags)){
    foreach($getDecisionTags as $key => $val){ ?>
       
        states.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
    <?php } } ?>


    ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
                'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
                'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
                'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
                'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
                'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
                'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
                'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
                'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
            ];
    $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'states',
        source: substringMatcher(states)
    });
```

Livewire controller code

```
public function render()
    {
            $getTags =   DecisionTag::where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', authUserId())->orWhere('user_id', authCompanyId())->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->whereIn('user_id', getProfiles()); 
            });
        })->select('tag')->where('tag', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->searchTag.'%')->groupBy('tag')->get();

        foreach($getTags as $getTag){
                $this->getDecisionTags[] = $getTag->tag;
            }
        return view('livewire.dashboard.auto-suggetion');
    }

enter code here
```